# Display Most Viewed Pages in Sharepoint and Filter by a PageTag

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I want to display the most viewed pages with certain flags on my SharePoint homepage. I use Sharepoint Online.

I used the "Highlighted Content" web part and sorted by "Most viewed". But the sites that are displayed are not the ones which are interesting but sites like the Homepage itself. How can I setup a filter to specify which pages to display? I wanted to add a column to the pages-table and define a tag. But I don't know how to filter by that tag in the highlighted content web part.

PS: I know there is a similar question out here but I don't have enough reputation to comment (but to ask a new question???). Would be nice if this could get maybe a few upvotes so that I can simply comment in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up the labels manually? Assuming that the label has been set and you want to filter based on the label column, then you need to set the Managed Property for search and filter.You can check this article:[Setup SharePoint Highlighted Content Webpart For Managed Property Filter](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-managed-property-search/)